# Laravel Vue js router param disappear when refresh

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am using laravel 5.8 and Vuejs2 
How to prevent disappear edit id from router param when refresh page

This is my router link

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'editEmployee', params: { id:employee.id } }" 
 title="Edit">
      Edit
  </router-link>
```

and this is my defined route

```
{ path: '/editemployee', component: require('./components/EditEmployee.vue').default, name: 'editEmployee',meta: {title: 'Edit Employee' } },
```

And this is how am checking param id in editEmployee component

```
created() {
 if (this.$route.params.id) {
   this.editMode = true;
   this.loadUser(this.$route.params.id);
 }
}
```

But when i refresh page the param id is disappearing from route. 
how can i prevent disappearing id from route when i refresh page

Anyone can help me?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the id param in your route

```
path: '/editemployee/:id'
```

Comment: got it. Thank you